# Finding real solution(s) to a complex equation

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have a matrix `matA` defined as

```
 matA = {{y + Re[2 x2 x6 - x7], 
    x6 Re[x1], -(x5/2) - Im[2 x2 x6 - x7], -x6 Im[x1], 0, x6 Re[x1], 
    0, x6 Im[x1]}, {x6 Re[x1], y - x8, -x6 Im[x1], -(x4/2), x6 Re[x1],
     0, x6 Im[x1], 0}, {x5/2 + Im[2 x2 x6 - x7], x6 Im[x1], 
    y + Re[2 x2 x6 - x7], x6 Re[x1], 0, x6 Im[x1], 
    0, -x6 Re[x1]}, {x6 Im[x1], x4/2, x6 Re[x1], y - x8, x6 Im[x1], 
    0, -x6 Re[x1], 0}, {0, -x6 Re[x1], 0, -x6 Im[x1], 
    y - Re[2 x2 x6 - x7], -x6 Re[x1], x5/2 + Im[2 x2 x6 - x7], 
    x6 Im[x1]}, {-x6 Re[x1], 0, -x6 Im[x1], 0, -x6 Re[x1], y + x8, 
    x6 Im[x1], x4/2}, {0, -x6 Im[x1], 0, 
    x6 Re[x1], -(x5/2) - Im[2 x2 x6 - x7], -x6 Im[x1], 
    y - Re[2 x2 x6 - x7], -x6 Re[x1]}, {-x6 Im[x1], 0, x6 Re[x1], 
    0, -x6 Im[x1], -(x4/2), -x6 Re[x1], y + x8}};
```

The variables `x1` and `x2` are complex which satisfy the following equations

```
 Reduce[{x1 == x3/(x5/2 - I (2 x6 x2 - x7)), 
   x2 == (I x6 x1^2)/(I x8 + x4/2)}, {x1, x2}]
```

All other variables `x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8` are real (and positive). I want to find a real value of `y` such that `Det[matA] == 0`. I am approaching with hit-n-trial but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Reduce[{x1==x3/(x5/2-I (2 x6 x2-x7)),x2==(I x6 x1^2)/(I x8+x4/2),
x3>0,x4>0,x5>0,x6>0,x7>0,x8>0,Element[y,Reals],Det[matA]==0},y]` seems like the simplest thing to try, but with that many variables it may take a very long time or it may never find it. Trying `Simplify[Det[matA]]` first doesn't seem to help. Trying to find any `y` without limiting it to being `Real` doesn't seem to help. Doing `Simplify[Reduce[{x1 == x3/(x5/2 - I (2 x6 x2 - x7)),  x2 == (I x6 x1^2)/(I x8 + x4/2)}, {x1, x2}],x3>0&&x6>0]` first shows you have a pretty ugly cubic and that is probably making it slower.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, there are too many variables involved here.

Comment: This is large enough that it might not be tractable.

Answer (score 0):

Its not so clear to me why this problem is formulated in complex terms, if Re and Im are used. Re Im are very difficult to handle in automatic evaluations.

So one switches to real variables

```
 toR = {x1 -> u + I v, x2 -> w + I z}
```

and the expansion for sums and products

```
 ReImExpand=  
  {f_ [x__Plus ] :> f /@ x /; f == Re || f == Im,
  f_[x_Symbol | x_Integer] :> x /; f == Re || f == Im,
  f_[(x_Symbol  | x_Integer )*y__] :> x f[y] /; f == Re || f == Im}

sol = Solve[{x1 == x3/(x5/2 - I (2 x6 x2 - x7)), 
  x2 == (I x6 x1^2)/(I x8 + x4/2)} /. ToR, {v, z}] // Simplify;
```

yields combinations of complex 3rd roots.

The processing of the determinant uses 6 GB and at 4 GHz,  aborted after 10 min.

```
mf = (matB =( (matA /.ToR}) //.ReImExpand) // MatrixForm;

Solve[Det[matB==0]]
Aborted
```

So one tries to isolate factors in the GroebnerBasis, that could nullify the determinant.

```
GrB = GroebnerBasis[Det[matB], {u, v, w, z}];
```

Most coefficients have a factor x6. So x6=0 is an easy shot.

```
(CoefficientList[GrB,{u,v,w,z}]//Flatten//Factor)/.x6->0//Union


 {0,
(x5^2-4 x5 x7+8 x7^2-8 x7 y+4 y^2)*
 (x5^2-4 x5 x7+8 x7^2+8 x7 y+4 y^2)* 
(x4^2+4 x8^2-8 x8 y+4 y^2) *
(x4^2+4 x8^2+8 x8 y+4 y^2)}

Solve[x4^2+4 x8^2+8 x8 y+4 y^2==0,y] 
{{y->-(1/2) I (x4-2 I x8)},{y->1/2 I (x4+2 I x8)}}


0==Det[matB /. {x6 -> 0, y -> 1/2 I (x4 + 2 I x8)}]
 True
```

More research can be done for x6!=0. I dont even try to go into evaluating the conditions.

```
Limit[v /. sol /. {y -> 1/2 I (x4 + 2 I x8)}, x6 -> 0]

    {DirectedInfinity[-( Sign[x4 (x5 + 2 I x7) + (-(x5 + 2 I x7)^3 (x4 + 2 I x8)^3)^(1/3) + 
    2 I x5 x8 - 4 x7 x8]/
    (-Sign[x5 + 2 I x7]^3 Sign[x4 + 2 I x8]^3)^(1/6))],
     
    DirectedInfinity[ Sign[(1 + I Sqrt[3]) (x5 + 2 I x7) (x4 + 2 I x8) + 
    (1-I Sqrt[3]) (-(x5 + 2 I x7)^3 (x4 + 2 I x8)^3)^(1/3)]/
    (-Sign[x5 + 2 I x7]^3 Sign[x4 + 2 I x8]^3)^(1/6)], 

DirectedInfinity[Sign[(I + Sqrt[3]) (-I x5 + 2 x7) (x4 + 2 I x8) + 
    (1 +I Sqrt[3]) (-(x5 + 2 I x7)^3 (x4 + 2 I x8)^3)^(1/3)]/
    (-Sign[x5 + 2 I x7]^3 Sign[x4 + 2 I x8]^3)^(1/6)]}
```